# I'm not getting matches on my multi-valued fields

Tags: search, solr, multivalue

I have a couple of multi-valued fields in my schema, but when I search on terms that should produce results from these fields, no results come back.

For example, in my schema there is a multi-valued field like this:

```
<field name="tag" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
```

When I do a search on a tag with a query like this ...

```
{!dismax q.op=AND}test
```

I get results with "test" in the single-valued fields, but not in the multi-valued fields. I dump the results I get back from searching to verify what is stored.

```
(matches when I search "test")
name: TEST 4
description: i match the query "test"
year: 2010
id: 61

(does not match when I search "test")
name: BEST 4
description: i do not match the query
year: 2010
id: 68
tags: (array)
  0:test
  1:test2
  2:i'm a test
```

I wasn't able to find similar problems with a search so I feel like I must have missed something. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: CSV in a database is pure evil. Never use it, because it will give you nothing but grief, slowness, duplication of data and other misery.

Comment: There's no CSV in the DB. I should have made it clearer this is a question about Solr. The multi-valued field is necessary to have a field with a variable number of values in it (for something like tags) in Solr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are the tags included into the list of searchable fields ?
What are the fields you are searching on ? you might want to add tags.

As you are using defType as dismax, you can try passing qf=tags in url to test if the the document with name BEST 4 is returned with the results.

Example solrconfig.xml entry for searching on name, description and tags -

```
<requestHandler name="dismax" class="solr.SearchHandler">
   <lst name="defaults">
     <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
     <str name="defType">dismax</str>
     <str name="qf">
        name description tags
     </str>
     <str name="q.alt">*:*</str>
     <str name="rows">10</str>
     <str name="fl">*,score</str>
   </lst>
</requestHandler>
```

use url as

```
q=test&qt=dismax
```

Comment: Thanks, adding "qf=tags" to the query caused me to get results from the tags field. I could swear I tried that before! I'll set up a request handler with default fields and that should resolve the issue. Thanks for the quick answer!